# git cmd formatting a log

Tags: git

I have a uni assignment to discuss the relationships in defective files for a given git repository. I am trying to generate a git log of the following format:

`file name + number of commits + current word count + number of contributors`

The best ive gotten so far is `git log --name-only --pretty=format: | sort | uniq -c >results.txt` 
which produces `number of commits + file name`

Comment: Can you add an example for the expected output format?

Comment: file1.java 10 55 4 
file2.java 4 1734 8 
file3.java 22 409 6 

i dont need an exact format, i just need the 4 pieces of information in a text file

Answer (score 0):

This script can do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Invoke as repodetails.bash /path/to/git/repo

git_repo_path=$1

cd $git_repo_path
echo "" > output.txt

# Get a list of tracked files in the current repository.
file_list=$(git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only)

for file in $file_list
do

# Get the count of commits by listing the commit history of the file.
commit_count=$(git log --oneline -- "$file" | wc -l)

# Use wc on the file to get the word count.
word_count=$(git show "HEAD:$file" | wc -w)

# Use the summary option of git shortlog to get a list of contributors.
author_count=$(git shortlog -s $file | wc -l)

echo "$file $commit_count $word_count $author_count" >> output.txt
done
```

As an example, I made a clone of this repo from GitHub: https://github.com/GitSquared/edex-ui to the /opt directory. Then, I ran my script as `./repodetails.bash /opt/edex-ui`. This generated a file named `output.txt` under `/opt/edex-ui`.

The output.txt file contains the required details in the following format:

```
src/classes/modal.class.js 2 165 1
src/classes/netstat.class.js 8 305 1
src/classes/ramwatcher.class.js 5 257 2
src/classes/sysinfo.class.js 6 291 1
src/classes/terminal.class.js 31 906 2
src/classes/toplist.class.js 2 95 1
src/classes/updateChecker.class.js 4 190 1
src/package-lock.json 55 685 3
src/package.json 68 65 5
src/ui.html 20 161 1
```

Comment: Sorry im completely new to git. How do i run this script exactly? I have the repository on my local machine. Also thanks a lot!

Comment: @user322394 1) Create a file anywhere in your system with the name `repodetails.bash`. 2) Copy the script contents from here to that file. 3) Run the script as `bash repodetails.bash /path/to/local/repository`. The remaining execution details are included in my answer.

Comment: @user322394 Here's a link to a tutorial site, with slightly more detailed instructions: https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-write-and-execute-a-shell-script

Comment: Im on windows 10. Still struggling to run this script.

Comment: This site is for Unix & Linux questions, and my script is therefore written for a Linux environment. If you have Git Bash on your Windows system, you can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36401147/6216002